# he knocks ashes out against the bars?

Tags: meaning, context

I'm reading  Jerome K. Jerome's 'Three men in a boat'
The above is about fishermen's bluff.
My question is in the above paragraph a man knocks ashes (from his pipe) against the bars. 
But what is bars? On the counter? or on the window bars? 
But it is not likely under the circumstances, so I just wonder if 'bars' mean something different or particular meaning in this context.

Comment: You will have to go to a 19th century fisherman's pub and look around.

Comment: You really need to include some context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't tell from the context in the story. I would knock out a pipe against the bars of an open fire (if I smoked a pipe and lived in a C19 novel)

[image: Victorian coal fireplace]

Comment: If it meant the counter of a pub it would be 'against the bar', and since windows don't usually have bars in English pubs (at least not the sort Jerome went into) I think the fire is right.

Comment: An open fire *per se* does not exactly have bars either. The bars belong rather to the grate or [firebasket](http://www.salvosites.com/antique-fireplaces/reclaimed-victorian-style-cast-iron-fire-basket-64768.html) that holds up the burning bits of wood or coal so that they can get air from beneath.

Comment: Also, the speaker has appropriated the most comfortable chair, which is very likely to be one by the fireside.

Comment: @BrianDonovan it has bars at the front to stop the coal falling out. This is England so coal fired rather than N American wood hearth